# SQL Query ORDER BY column values

Tags: sql

I have a column which can take any values from 0 to 100.

Now i have a type TYPE1 which can take values 2, 4, 16

TYPE2 which can take values 8,12,64.

Now i want to sort the column by TYPE1 values first and then TYPE2 values. Is there any way to do that.

My column has only these values. It does not know the Type1 or Type2. I am using SQL2005

NOTE: TYPE1 and TYPE2 are not columns. They are just logical entities.

Comment: "My column has only these values" -- how does your one column hold three values e.g. are you using `CREATE TYPE TYPE1 AS TABLE...`?

Comment: By these values i mean they hold numbers ranging from 0 to 100 in each no row. It does not hold 3 values in a single column for a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify both columns in `ORDER BY` caluse:

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable ORDER BY Type1, Type2
```

This would by default sort the fields in ascending order. If you want to order in reverse, you can use `DESC` keyword just after column names.

Comment: @ckv: You can replace Type1 and Type2 with your actual column names you want to sort against, the syntax will be the same.

Comment: Hey Sarfraz, Yeah i can replace the column name with exact name but the problem is i will get sorted in a mixed way. I want to sort in such a way that i get 2, 4, 16 as one set and rest as other. Because the TYPE2 has a value 8 which will come in between.

Answer (score 2):

What are TYPE1 and TYPE2 and what is your database?
In MySQL you can do `ORDER BY FIELD(columnnane, 2,4,16,8,12,64)`

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple fields to the Order By Clause

```
select type1, type2 from table order by type1, type2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY type1, type2 -- the columns you want to sort in order
```

Answer (score 0):

use a case to separate type 1 and type 2, then order by the column:

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable ORDER BY case when column in (2,4,16) then 1, else 2 end,column
```

This way, first you order by type 1 or 2, them order by value of the column