# Order by asc in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need to sort the number from ascending value. sample data is

```
463919493       
463919493 02
463919493 02
463919493 03
463919493 01
463919493 03
463919493 01
```

i need to get output as

```
463919493       
463919493 01
463919493 01
463919493 02
463919493 02
463919493 03
463919493 03
```

and suppose if we have alphabet with number, how to sort this number in asscending

```
  HO463919493       
  HO463919493 02
  HO463919493 02
  HO463919493 03
  HO463919493 01
  HO463919493 03
  HO463919493 01
```

Need to get output as:

```
 HO463919493       
 HO463919493 01
 HO463919493 01
 HO463919493 02
 HO463919493 02
 HO463919493 03
 HO463919493 03
```

Comment: Is that 1 column or 2? The table definition and your query would go far here. Also the SQL version/dbms as well.

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  Is that one column or two?  What database are you using?  What happens if the first "column" has different values?

Comment: Please post a query that you are having trouble with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Query ORDER BY column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465712/sql-query-order-by-column-values)

Comment: Poor sample data, same value all over a column.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2060952/223752

Answer (score 0):

SYNTAX:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table
ORDER BY
    col1 asc
```

For multiple column:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table
ORDER BY
    col1 asc,
    col2 desc
```